# Displaying data that is not expired by expirydate column of my table by comparing with getdate

Tags: sql

I have a table containing column `expirydate` which is `datetime` column. I want to display only data that is not expired.
I tried `ExpiryDate<GetDate()` in where along with other filters
But it doesn't show any result if I put expirydate filter.Without expirtydatefilter it works fine.
Please Help,This is my Query

**QUERY**

```
SELECT AdId, CreatedId, 
CreatedName, AdEmail, 
PostName, AdTopic, 
[Description], SocietyId, 
SocietyName, SocietyUserId, 
SocietyUserName, SocietyUserEmailId, 
IsAccepted, IsRejected, 
IsActive, CreatedDate, 
ExpiryDate, City, 
[Type], Category
FROM dbo.tblClassifedDetails
WHERE IsAccepted='true' 
AND ExpiryDate<GETDATE() 
AND @Type=[Type] 
AND Category=case 
WHEN @Category  IS NULL
OR @Category='' 
OR @Category='All' 
THEN Category 
ELSE @Category 
END
AND City=case 
WHEN @City  IS NULL
OR @City='' 
OR @City='All' 
THEN City 
ELSE @City 
END
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

convert(date,GETDATE())Try this

```
select AdId, CreatedId, CreatedName, AdEmail, PostName, AdTopic, 
       [Description], SocietyId, SocietyName, SocietyUserId, SocietyUserName, 
       SocietyUserEmailId, IsAccepted, IsRejected, IsActive, CreatedDate, 
       ExpiryDate, City, [Type], Category
from dbo.tblClassifedDetails
where IsAccepted='true' 
and convert(date,ExpiryDate)>=convert(date,GETDATE()) 
and @Type=[Type] 
and Category= (case when @Category  is null or @Category='' or @Category='All' 
                    then Category 
               else @Category end)
and City=(case when @City  is null or @City='' or @City='All' 
               then City 
          else @City end)
```

Comment: thanx for this much quick reply.

Comment: Please do NOT use functions on the ExpiryDate, it probably isn't needed and it will slow dow the query. Also instead of convert(date,getdate()) you can use: dateadd(dd, datediff(day,0, getDate()), 0) which also "truncates" the time to leave you with just the date, but returns a datetime value.

Comment: Expected but doubted as there is no sample data for expiry date. I believe it is easy to use convert as there is only casting but dateadd and datediff will consume more time as u need to caluclate diff of days from 1900:01:01 and again add them which will give current date which is too complex.